# javascript custom method for checking if element exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a rookie at javascript, I have just gone through few of array methods and wanted to play with it, I'm stuck at this code that I've written:

```
function customFindProperty(arrayToFind,requiredItem){

  var elementIndex = 0;

  function isRequiredItem(item){
    elementIndex++;
    return item==requiredItem;
  }

  elementFound = arrayToFind.some(isRequiredItem);

  if(elementFound){
    return arrayToFind(elementIndex);
  } else{
    alert("Element Not Found");
    return undefined;
  }
}
var myElement = customFindProperty([1,2,3,4,5],3);
```

This gives me the error  **TypeError: Object is not a function** I think I'm not even missing any semicolons.

Additional Info:
`typeof customFindProperty` returns "function"

**Note**
Don't know how to close this question I found the answer it's a simple typing mistake I was trying to return arrayToFind(elementIndex) instead of arrayToFind[elementIndex]

Comment: Is that a real typo?  i.e. calling `customFindPropety` instead of `customFindProperty`?  Maybe that's the problem.  At any rate, you need to say which line the error is coming from.

Comment: `some` expects a callable function

Comment: `arrayToFind(elementIndex);` is an array right? So it should be `arrayToFind[elementIndex];`?

Comment: @veresdesmarald: Thanks ! how silly mistake it was

Comment: @veredesmarald you should post your comment as an answer and Unspecified should mark it as the answer :)

Comment: On a side note, I think your var elementIndex should be initialized as -1 instead of 0, because you are incrementing it before checking for the required item.

Comment: yeah lots of issues...need to fix 'em up, Thank u guys fr ur suggestions :)

Comment: @MattFenwick: typo was made while writing the code on stack overflow, else I'd have got some other error before my TypeError, btw edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parentheses instead of square brackets for your array access. `arrayToFind(elementIndex);` should be `arrayToFind[elementIndex];`.

Answer (score 0):

return arrayToFind[elementIndex]

Your using parens, like you're calling a function. Square bracelets are used for array access.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayToFind` - is this a function? It's not, and you're trying to call it and it's failing.

By the way you've used it here - `arrayToFind.some`, we can assume it's an array, you need to index it with **square brackets** to return a value, like so:

```
arrayToFind[elementIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can simply this a lot further..

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

var itemToFind = 3;

var indexOfMyItem = arr.indexOf(itemToFind); // -1 would mean not found
```

So it comes down to -

```
 return indexOfMyItem > -1 ? arr[itemToFind] : undefined;
```

Comment: ya I know "indexOf" exists, but what if I have a array of objects & I want to find an object based on some property...getting me ? that's what I'm trying to implement by myself

Comment: @Unspecified: I totally see your point now. Well, your question has the `item==requiredItem` check which led me to posting this answer.

Comment: ya Thanks btw...Actually Ember-Data has this findProperty() method on their store objects, so b4 peeking into the source-code I thought I'd give it a shot on my own :)

Comment: nd Ofcourse I want to return a single object not an array of elements matching my criteria which I can implement using array filter() method...

Comment: @Unspecified: Considering all what you have said. I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer. You should consider updating your question with more requirements/details.

Comment: As u can see from my question, I just wanted to know the cause of typeError which was hindering my progress in coming up with what I said...Firstly, I shudn't post such questions on stack with out analyzing, that's why i flagged my question & thankfully the moderator closed it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt. I think the problem is the name of the function

Your function's name is `customFindProperty` and you're calling `customFindPropety` (note the r of property).

If you change this, the next problem is with 'some', because arrayToFind is not a function